# Webpack. Build components library

Tags: webpack

I want to build my components library, for example like in Material-UI.

All build should goes through directories dynamically

One thing that I can't figure out is assembling each button, select, etc - separately, so that you end up with this in the dist directory:

`dist/Buttons/PrimaryButton/PrimaryButton.js`

`dist/Buttons/PrimaryButton/SecondaryButton.js`

my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/components/lib.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: "",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(j|t)s?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "assets/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "src/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
      constants: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/constants"),
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
      styleguide: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styleguide")
    }
  }
};
```

My PrimaryButton:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.sass";
import { IButton } from "components/Buttons/Interfaces/IButton";

const PrimaryButton: React.FC<IButton> = ({ children, onClick, ...rest }) => {
  const handleClickButton = () => {
    onClick();
  };
  return (
    <button className="primary-button" onClick={handleClickButton} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default PrimaryButton;
```

And lib.ts:

```
import PrimaryButton from "./Buttons/PrimaryButton/PrimaryButton";

export { PrimaryButton };
```

On google I found something like this, but it builds my index.js file, without the button, which I export to lib.js

Answer (score 0):

You might check the [webpack docs on entry points](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#entry-points) and its various options:

```
  entry: {
    "Buttons/PrimaryButton/PrimaryButton": './src/path/to/primaryButton.js',
    "Buttons/PrimaryButton/SecondaryButton": './src/path/to/secondaryButton.js',
  },
```

Comment: No. It should be dynamically. I know about multiple entries :)

Comment: @Marty I have not found another built in solution but came to the idea, that you could create a dynamic entry function. This function checks on each build your component folder for available files and returns the desired object list of entry points.